# Доступ к label slider и т.д. из другого окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Как получить доступ к элементам окна (label,slider) из обработчика событий другого окна?

Comment: Это можно, но не нужно. Не дело чужому окну лазить по внутренностям этого окна. Расскажите лучше, чего вы хотите добиться этим.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы окну с которым хочется взаимодействовать не предоставить открытые методы для этого?

А в событии вы сможете привести объект к нужному типу и вызвать эти методы.

Это самый простой вариант и не нарушает инкапсуляцию.

Есть еще вариант:

Можно все объекты окна сделать публичными, но это не совсем правильно, так как любой желающий сможет делать, что ему вздумается, а так же рушится инкапсуляция.